# How to make LinearGradient with list of colors?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using `LinearGradient` which supports only 2 colors. And i want to make gradient with list of colors and set it programmatically.

Comment: Why are you convinced that `LinearGradient` _supports only 2 colors_?  The documentation says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LinearGradient Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient)

You can specify an array of colors and the LinearGradient class will automatically draw them distributed evenly along the gradient line.

Example:

```
float[] positions = null;
int[] colors = {
    Color.BLACK,
    Color.RED,
    Color.GREEN
};
paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, (float)bounds.width(), 0f, colors, positions, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```